# Moq property of an object specified by an Interface

Tags: c#, .net, moq

Is there a way to moq a property of an object that Interface exposes?

having:

```
interface IMyInterface {
   CurrentContact CurrentContact { get; }
}
```

Contact class has a field "BirtDate" that is used somewhere in the code, and therefore needs to be mocked

```
public class CurrentContact : ContactEntity
  {
    public IEnumerable<CustomerAddress> ContactAddresses { get; }
    public Organization ContactOrganization { get; }
...
```

So I do:

```
customerContextMock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
customerContextMock.Setup(x => x.CurrentContact.BirthDate)
                .Returns(new CustomerContact {BirthDate = DateTime.MaxValue}.BirthDate);
```

However I get the following error

> Additional information: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in
>   VB) member: x => x.CurrentContact.BirthDate

is there anyway to mock this without adding this (and anyo ther fields) I need to moq to IMyInterface as properties?

Comment: Can you show the `Contact` class?

Comment: it's a third party library with bunch of get{} properties that are not virtual

Comment: You cannot mock non virtual properties. You can set them if they have a setter, however.

Comment: Now your property `CurrentContact` is missing a type

Comment: is there a way to create a Fake that inherits CurrentContact and use "new" keyword to add a setter?. would that work?

Comment: Not with `new`, but maybe there is a constructor that allows you to set `BirthDate`. It would be a lot easier for us to help you if you show the relevant parts of the `Contact` class.

Comment: there's no constructor. CurrentContact class has bunch of properties get{}. that's it.

Comment: In your production code, how do these properties get their values?

Comment: i don't know. it's a third party library. i believe its coming from a session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend creating an interface `IContact` in your code with all properties you need from the third party `Contact` class. Then use the [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to connect to the `Contact` class. Finally you can mock the whole `IContact` interface. This approach has also the big advantage, that you are independent of the third party `Contact` class in you whole application except in the contact adapter class.

In more detail this could look something like this:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
  IContact CurrentContact { get; }
}

public interface IContact
{
  DateTime BirthDate { get; }
  // define more needed properties here
}

public class ContactAdapter : IContact
{
  private readonly Contact _contact;

  public ContactAdapter(Contact contact)
  {
    _contact = contact;
  }

  public DateTime BirthDate
  {
    get { return _contact.BirthDate; }
  }

  // delegate more properties to third party Contact class
}
```

So you can mock the whole `IContact` with something like this for example:

```
var contactMock = new Mock<IContact>();
contactMock.Setup(c => c.BirthDate).Returns(DateTime.MaxValue);
```

As a last step you have to wire up the `IContact` interface to use the `ContactAdapter` in your production code. As you can see above, the `ContactAdapter` gets the third party `Contact` class as constructor argument.
Ideally, you'd use an IoC container to setup the wiring.